# Cannot add computer to active directory using LDAP

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

Using the following code:

```
Private Sub Button12_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsubmit.Click

    'see if it already exists
    If DirectoryEntry.Exists("LDAP://CN=" & AdEntry.Text & ",OU=" & Machinetype.Text & ",OU=Computers,OU=" & USlocation.Text & ",OU=North America,DC=company,DC=com") = True Then
        MsgBox("Object already exists")
    Else

        Try

            'Set the directory entry
            Dim de As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=" & Machinetype.Text & ",OU=Computers,OU=" & USlocation.Text & ",OU=North America,DC=company,DC=com")
            Dim newComputer As DirectoryEntry = de.Children.Add("CN=TESTER", "computer")

            newComputer.CommitChanges()
            MsgBox("Computer added!")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error adding computer")
        End Try

    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180851(v=VS.80).aspx this should work, but it returns an exception.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Can you print the exception instead of printing your own error message. That might help.

Comment: Turns out this was an issue with my AD server. Thanks!